# Re-rendering when bootstrapping in client side

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using Angular 7 for my application. It is client-side rendering with entire HTML being cached ( DOM for the App) in local storage using service worker. For subsequent page request, HTML is being served from local storage. Idea is that the browser will render cached HTML first providing fast perceived page load experience and then the app will bootstrap and hydrate the view. The issue I am currently facing is that when app bootstraps and page is re-rendered, it is causing flickering. Is there a way to eliminate this flickering.

Comment: You're storing the entire dom in cache?! I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but I'm sure there's a better way.  Without more context it's impossible to say.

Comment: Why not use service workers and create a Progressive web app, more info here [**Getting started with service workers**](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#getting-started-with-service-workers)

Comment: Yes, It is render caching that I am trying to implement in Angular. I am using service worker and is a progressive app. https://css-tricks.com/render-caching-for-react/.